# ASP.NET - Query'ing table with string ID and 2 keys

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, key

I'm currently stuck on a piece of code that returns exception:

CONTROLLER:

```
 public ActionResult Edit (string userId)
    {
        AspNetUserRoles personRole;
        if (userId == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        ///error happens here during execution of  Find() on table
        personRole = tbls.AspNetUserRoles.Find(userId);


        if (personRole == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(personRole);
    }
```

VIEW (through which I pass string ID):

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.MyViewModel>



<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleId)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*I added null, so for the sake of routing*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Home", new { id = item.Id }, null) |



            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

MODELS:

```
  public class MyViewModel
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class AspNetUserRoles
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public string RoleId { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    }
}

public partial class AspNetUsers
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AspNetUsers()
        {
            AspNetUserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserRoles>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }

        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I wonder what could be wrong here. I can loop through joined AspNetUsers and AspNetUserRoles on the string ID and it gives all records (typed against MyViewModel). Then in the View I want to be able to get to the particular record typed against AspNetUserRoles and be able to edit it, though it's irrelevant now since I can't get the right record while querying the database.

My thoughts were that it's either the problem with routing using @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Home", new { id = item.Id }, null)     (checked what URI looks like and it's correct meaning controller/action/parameter is ok, also during debbuging string Id wasn't null)  or  rather problem with Find() method while it takes string argument or the fact that I'm querying table which has 2 keys (though it's just an idea nothing solid).

Any lead could be usefull.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find` method finds entities using primary keys. As you have *composite primary key* on `AspNetUserRoles` model you have to provide both keys to find entity:

```
personRole = tbls.AspNetUserRoles.Find(userId, roleId);
```

`roleId` is the id of role you want to find. If you have only one role associated with user, then you can query and get it as:

```
personRole = tbls.AspNetUserRoles.Single(m => m.UserId == userId);
```

But keep in mind that if user has more than one role above code will throw exception.

Read more about finding entities [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx).

Comment: will check in a minute, thank you - it is designed to have one 1 role

Comment: thank you very much - it worked - the solution was to add                        personRole = tbls.AspNetUserRoles.Single(m => m.UserId == userId);             instead of                        personRole = tbls.AspNetUserRoles.Single(userId);        now I'm facing another problem but still helped me very much :)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. Try to solve another problem yourself. If you can't solve it after trying you can find help again in StackOverflow